# como separar correctamente cada token y hacer las operaciones

Tags: java

Desarrolle un programa que calcule una operación matemática introducida en una maquina pero divididas las operaciones entre dos equipos de computo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
st= new StringTokenizer(ecuacion," ");
while(st.hasMoreTokens()){
    this.muestra.append(st.nextToken()+"\n");
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores 1 inicial :" + ecuacion);
while (ecuacion.contains("*") || ecuacion.contains("/")) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores * / " + ecuacion);
    operador = st.nextToken().charAt(0);//obtenemos el operador
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores 2 " + operador);
    op2 = Double.parseDouble(st.nextToken());//obtenemos el segundo operador
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores 3 " + operador);
    String operacion = op1 + " " + operador + " " + op2;//construimos la operacion
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores 4 " + operacion);
    if (operador == '*') {//si es multiplicacion la resuleve el server
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"operadores 5 " + operador);
        resultado = op1 * op2;//guardamos el resultado
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"resultado de server " + resultado);
        //sustituimos la operacion por el resultado
        ecuacion = ecuacion.replace(operacion, resultado + "");
        mostrar(ecuacion + "\n"); //mostramos la ecuacion simplificada
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"resultado ecua " + ecuacion);
    } else if (operador == '/') {//si es divicion la resuelve el cliente
        //enviamos al cliente la operacion y le indicamos que es divicion
        //enviarDatos(operacion + "|/");
        //guardamos el resultado que se reciba del cliente
        //resultado = Double.parseDouble(entrada.readUTF());
        //sustituimos la operacion por el resultado
        ecuacion = ecuacion.replace(operacion, resultado + "");
        mostrar(ecuacion + "\n"); //mostramos la ecuacion simplificada
    }
    op1 = op2;//ahora el segundo operando sera el primer operando para despues buscar el operador
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Hola! las preguntas sobre ejercicios a resolver no son bien vistas y son cerradas, salvo que muestres que hiciste hasta ahora, y expliques un problema puntual en tu codigo. Saludos!

Comment: este es mi codigo pero no se en que estoy mal intento separar por tokens pero no puedo

Comment: lo que pusiste como respuesta, tiene que ir como una edicion aca. Usa el boton [edit], agrega el codigo relevante aca, explica donde esta el error, usa CTRL+K para que quede formateado, y se claro con el problema.

Comment: en que parte estas intentando separar que cosa por token?

Comment: StringTokenizer st= new StringTokenizer(ecuacion," "); Antes ya quito paréntesis y reemplazo paréntesis con espacios

Comment: pero esa funcion solo divide los tokens por lo que estas pasando, que es un espacio. ahi esta tu principal error. Aca cada simbolo matematico y cada numero es un token...

Comment: no se en que guardar o como guardar cada numero y seleccionar cada simbolo de operación para despues hacer las operaciones

Comment: gracias amigo seguire adelante intentándolo espero resolverlo gracias